# What is the difference between @aws-cdk/pipelines and @aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

These two packages seem to largely do the same thing? What is the intended difference between these two packages and also which should I be using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pipelines is the newer --experimental-- (Edit: It is no longer in Experimental, but now a proper library) library. It has additional constructs like "SimpleSynth" and can do things like check the code for the pipeline and update the pipeline along with deploying your code/infrastructure. It incorporates a lot of CodePipelineActions into the same constructs that create the stages - I suppose the idea is to remove a little of the customization to make it a bit easier to code (generally cuts the number of instantiation in half of various constructs)

In most cases, it's kind of an overkill. Plus until you and your team have a lot of Base knowledge of cdk it can be dangerous - the self-mutating aspect of your pipeline being able to update and mutate itself when you update your source (a thing that CICD likes) can mean if you make a mistake you can lock your app out of deploying.

Also  it's still experimental - meaning they may break dependencies or invalidate older methods at any time.

I'd stick with CodePipeline and CodePipelineActions until you're very comfortable with using cdk and using it for a pipeline in general before experimenting with Pipelines (and generally any library that doesn't start with aws! Except Core most of those are experimental)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was actually trying to setup CI/CD and was trying to figure out how to use codedeploy which seems completely impossible with Pipelines at the moment since a deploy action doesn't even exist.

Comment: Yeah, deploy is there - but it is obfuscated behind SinpleSynth. Pipelines is also meant more to integrate your CDK stack of your application with the Pipeline directly (which is what SimpleSynth does - code deploy with cdk and all the necessary surrounding parts)